# Cannot install Aptana Studio on Windows 10: Failed to Correctly Aquire installer_git_windows.exe file: CRC Error

Tags: installation, aptana

Whenever I run the standalone installer for Aptana Studio I get the following error:

Failed to Correctly Aquire installer_git_windows.exe file: CRC Error

I'm running Windows 10, I've looked online for hours and have found no solution.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem solved by installing the Git from http://go.appcelerator.com/installer_git_windows.exe.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error.  I believe it still has something to do with the NodeJS.

I went to this site https://nodejs.org/en/download/  use the 32 bit version for Windows 10.  Then installed an older version of Aptana https://aptana-studio.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions with the 3.4.2   and tada.. it worked. I don't mind the older version for now.

Answer (score 3):

1. Rename the installer file to "aptana.exe"
2. Move that file to c drive
3. Open CMD in administrator mode Type "c:/aptana.exe /passive /norestart"
4. Press enter
5. After some process, a new exe file will be available on desktop which you can use.

It worked for me.

Comment: No need to rename or move the installer to the root of C drive, just open CMD to the path where you downloaded that installer, using the filename of that installer and the `/passive /norestart` flags as indicated (for example, `C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\Aptana_Studio_3_Setup.exe /passive /norestart`), the installation completes without prompting the user for any parameters, so Aptana ends up installed in the default folder (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio`) and ready to use, via a shortcut that the installer creates on the desktop.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me too and i believe it will work for everyone.
You can even not to copy and rename the installer, just as said launch the CMD as administrator and launch by changing directory to where the installer is located or mentioning the  full path to it with mentioned arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Simply download git from https://git-scm.com/download/win and install it manually before launching the Aptana installer and it will work.

Comment: This works well. thanks.